# How can I import an image over an icon image in react?

Tags: html, reactjs, image, icons, timeline

How can I exchange the `icon = {<AiOutlineFileDone/>}` for a jpeg or png image file
as shown below:

```
import { VerticalTimeline, VerticalTimelineElement } from 'react-vertical-timeline-component';
....

<VerticalTimeline >
            <VerticalTimelineElement
                className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
                contentStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#131414' }}
                contentArrowStyle={{ borderRight: '7px solid  rgb(33, 150, 243)' }}
                date="November 2020"
                iconStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#fff' }}
                icon = {<AiOutlineFileDone/>}

            >
                <h3 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">Title</h3>
                <h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">Location</h4>
                <p>
                    some info ...
                </p>
            </VerticalTimelineElement>
</VerticalTimeline>
```

check out this [link](https://github.com/stephane-monnot/react-vertical-timeline/blob/master/README.md) to see the output or result of the code. I am just looking to add an image over the the icons in the middle.

Comment: It probably accepts any component. Try `icon={<img src={someImg} />}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can import the path to the image you want to use and then use `<img>` element to render your image. Hope this helps.

```
import { VerticalTimeline, VerticalTimelineElement } from 'react-vertical-timeline-component';
import myImgSrc from '../path/to/image.png';
....

<VerticalTimeline >
            <VerticalTimelineElement
                className="vertical-timeline-element--work"
                contentStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#131414' }}
                contentArrowStyle={{ borderRight: '7px solid  rgb(33, 150, 243)' }}
                date="November 2020"
                iconStyle={{ background: 'rgb(33, 150, 243)', color: '#fff' }}
                icon = {<img src={myImgSrc} />}

            >
                <h3 className="vertical-timeline-element-title">Title</h3>
                <h4 className="vertical-timeline-element-subtitle">Location</h4>
                <p>
                    some info ...
                </p>
            </VerticalTimelineElement>
</VerticalTimeline>
```

Comment: I have tried that but the image does not auto configure to the circle in middle. As provided in the link above.

Comment: You can style the image using equal width and height and a border-radius of 50%, I found this sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/7mzjnrm280?file=/src/styles.css:303-315 that achieves what you want